# Set a default upload folder for an Image to go into in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 I have a class extending `DataObject` that has_one `Image`.

How can I specify a particular folder for the image files to be uploaded into when the user uploads an image from the CMS?

Answer (score 2):

In my class getCMSFields function, I got the UploadField for the Image then called the setFolderName function:

```
class BannerImage extends DataObject {
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page',
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        /** @var  UploadField $uploadField */
        $uploadField = $fields->fieldByName('Root.Main.Image');
        $uploadField->setFolderName("banners");
    ...
```

Comment: Your contribution was very helpful, thank you very much!